# How to read timestamp type's data from sql server using C#?

Tags: c#, timestamp, rowversion

I get the result in .NET like this:

```
var lastRowVersion = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connStr, CommandType.Text, "select
top 1 rowversion from dbo.sdb_x_orginfo order by rowversion desc");
```

The result is a byte array `[0]= 0,[1]=0,[2]=0,[3]=0,[4]=0,[5]=0,[6]=30,[7]=138`, but the result in SQL Server is `0x0000000000001E8A`.

How can I get the value `"0x0000000000001E8A"` in .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to convert `byte[]` to a `System.Int64` (aka `long`) then use [`BitConverter.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64.aspx):

```
SqlBinary binary = /* ... */;
long value = BitConverter.ToInt64(binary.Value, 0); // 0 is the start index in the byte array
```

To display it as a hex string, you can use the `X` [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value is 0x{0:X}.", value);
```

Comment: See the other answer - SqlBinary.Value has the opposite endianness, so you most likely want to reverse the bytes.

Answer (score 26):

I found that the byte[] returned from sql server had the wrong Endian-ness and hence the conversion to long (Int64) did not work correctly.  I solved the issue by calling Reverse on the array before passing it into BitConverter:

```
byte[] byteArray = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8};

var value = BitConverter.ToUInt64(byteArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
```

Also, I thought it better to convert to UInt64.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an one-liner:

```
var byteArray = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 138 };

var rowVersion = "0x" + string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(byteArray, x => x.ToString("X2")));
```

The result is:

```
"0x0000000000001E8A"
```

Just be aware that there are [other options that perform better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa#624379).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query which will return bigint instead of returning hex.

`select top 1 cast(rowversion as bigint) rowversion from dbo.sdb_x_orginfo order by rowversion desc`

Comment: Be aware that bigint is a 64bit *signed* integer, whereas rowversion is a 64bit *unsigned* integer. Given a large enough rowversion value, casting to bigint will give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Same as "Ashish Singh" I returned to c# after converting to bigint on DB and used Int64 on the code side.
Converting to long/Int64/UInt64 in c#/VB gave wrong results.(even after reversing the array because of the little endian issue.)

Pay attention on the DB side that RowVersion timestamp has MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION() which indicates the last commited timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```
  var versionString = new StringBuilder();
  versionString.Append("0x");
  for (var i = 0; i < binary.Count(); i++)
  {
      versionString.Append(string.Format("{0:X}", binary[i]));
  }
  versionString.ToString(); // result
```